# Free deployment for Visual Basic 2010 Express application that requires admin rights

Tags: setup-deployment, visual-studio-express, vb.net-2010, admin-rights

I'm using VB.Net and Visual Basic Express 2010.  I'm looking to create a single .exe install file to distribute my application.  But in order for my application to work, I need to mark my app. as requiring admin rights.

Click Once is not really an option because it A) Doesn't support code that requires admin rights, and B) Doesn't compile into a single .exe

So my question is...

How do I create a single executable installer package for free that requires that the program run as an admin.

The reason I need admin rights is because my application writes to C:\Windows\System32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your installation process is simple, you can try using the free version of Advanced Installer (create a "Simple" project). It will generate an MSI package which installs your application resources.

To make your application request elevation, you can add an [application manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) to its main exe. In it you can set *requestedExecutionLevel* to **requireAdministrator**.

Answer (score 0):

You could run the program using a bat file converted to a exe and you could package your exe in that exe too using www.BatToExeConverter.com or http://download.cnet.com/Bat-To-Exe-Converter/3000-2069_4-10555897.html

Put this code on top of your bat file to get admin rights.

```
mkdir "%windir%\BatchGotAdmin"
if '%errorlevel%' == '0' (
rmdir "%windir%\BatchGotAdmin" & goto gotAdmin 
) else ( goto UACPrompt )

echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
echo UAC.ShellExecute %0, "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

"%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
exit /B

if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
pushd "%CD%"      
CD /D "%~dp0"
```

Comment: SO how would this work?  I have not done a lot with batch files, I understand their purpose,but not how to implement/use them correctly.  I also relativity new with programming.  

So correct me if I am wrong with my understanding of your answer.

You are suggesting that I create a batch file to launch the program that indicates admin rights for me program?  Or are you rather suggesting that I embed my program within a batch file. (Right now I have about 10 files I need to include)
My end goal would be to have my program launchable from the start menu, and it request for admin rights at start.

Comment: That's correct. you could package all your files in one exe using one of the links, and using the code above to request admin rights

Comment: Thanks.  I'll see what I can do with your info.  So I will be able to launch this from the start menu?